# sockets and thread closing in java multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

I just want to know if in a multithreaded TCP socket program if a socket is closed does the thread associated with it also gets closed/killed or not?

Comment: There is no reason for the thread to stop. Do you have some problem? Some code to show?

Comment: i have a multithreaded server,i was thinking if the thread does not close won't the program reach a point where it won't be able to spawn any more threads?

Comment: Of course you need to manage your threads. Again, edit your question and ask for some specific problem.

Comment: Socket closure has zero effect on threads. How exactly could it? It is up to the thread itself to exit as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple threads and no sockets, you can have multiple sockets and just one thread. There doesn't have to be any relationship between them.  If you make the assumption that each socket has a new thread, you may have to ensure you exit the thread once it is no longer needed.

However, you could use a cached ExecutorService to save creating lots of threads over time and you can let it manage how many threads are required.